# Nightwatch.js E2E - can it test Vue.js Single File Components Loaded via Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex, nightwatch.js, vue-material

Our case is:

- Vue.js
- Vuex
- Vue Router
- Single File Components

Vue Router repo has examples for Nightwatch.js E2E testing, but not for single file components.

When we tried, the result of tests of loading components, with

`.assert.elementPresent`

where not consistent. We tested clicking a `router-link` and looked for loading the corresponding single file component (SFC). That is, the current component was replaced on the page by the loaded component.

Our navigation is through a [Vue Material drawer](https://vuematerial.io/components/drawer)  drawer. But we believe this is not ann essential element. **But we may be wrong here.**

Was someone able to get consistent results of tests of loading of such components?